# How to delete using only the primary key?

Tags: linq-to-sql, primary-key, delete-row, delete-record

How do I delete a record using Linq to SQL using only the primary key, without having to retrieve the existing record from the database?

Comment: Don't have VS to test this at the moment but wouldn't it be something like this: DataContext.Widgets.Delete(new {id = 123})

Comment: FerretallicA - Nope, I would have figured that out if it was the case. :)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to create an instance of the object with the appropriate FK and then Attach() it to the context, Delete() it and then SubmitChanges() which will perform a delete without performing a sql select.

```
var foo1 = new Foo {Id = 1};
db.Foos.Attach(foo1);
db.Foos.Remove(foo1);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 4):

Linq to SQL: Delete an entity using Primary Key only - Omar AL ...

http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/10/30/linq-to-sql-delete-an-entity-using-primary-key-only.aspx

Comment: +1 yup  basically you need straight SQL for this, Linq-to-SQL doesn't support it natively....